# Trying to 'design' First native app for android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, user-experience, mobile-application

I am Trying to 'design' First native app for android. To start with this I have followed http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html this page line by line. But at the end of the tutorial, couldnt understand where should I start UI/html. Since I am an UI designer, I was expecting HTML5/CSS3 custom designed UI to be deployed in android app.

How to deploy HTML5/CSS3 custom UI in android sdk/eclipse environment?
If I am conceptually wrong, what are the correct procedures for android UI design?

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Android **IS NOT** HTML5/CSS3 !

Native Android development is done with Java, which is a Object-Orientated language. The Android framework parses a lot of stuff from XML to build UIs and create resources, but still is all Java.

If you want to use HTML5/CSS3 what u want to do is a web-app. You might disguise it putting inside a webview, but still is a webapp, and will perform just as poorly as any other webapp.

So, the question back to you, what do you want to do?

Comment: @Budius.. thanks for your prompt reply. Now tell me, then how to make good UI for android based native app? there are loads of native app available in market which appears with stunning UI..

Comment: There's no simple direct way, easy recipe for it, just like anything else in life that you want a good result, takes effort and the general approach is: read->study->test->debug->learn->repeat. The http://developer.android.com/training/ website is a very good start and I wish people were more keen to read it carefully. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The training you were following is about writing a native android app in Java. In a native app the user interface is not done with HTML/CSS.

If you have a site in HTML5/CSS you can view it in the browser or in a `WebView` inside a native app.